# use object method in vector loop c++

Tags: c++, vector

This is my class:

```
class A
{
public:
    int getVal(){return m_val;};
private:
    int m_val = 1;
}

class B
{
public:
    void print();
private:
    std::vector<A*> m_vA;
}
```

And now in print I have

```
void B::print()
{
    std::vector<A>::iterator it;
for(auto it = m_vA.begin(); it != m_vA.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it.getVal() << endl;
}
}
```

And I got this error:

```
error: no member named 'getVal' in 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<A *const *>'
```

I don't understand why

Thanks for your help

Comment: `(*it).getVal()` or `it->getVal()`. [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various issues. First, you have an operator precedence problem. The expression in question is read like this:

```
*(it.getVal())
```

You can use either

```
it->getVal()
```

or

```
(*it).getVal()
```

Next, your vector is of type `std::vector<A*>`, but your iterator is `std::vector<A>::iterator`. That cannot work. My anwer depends on the vector being `std::vector<A>`. If it were `std::vector<A*>` then you need an extra level of de-referencing:

```
(*it)->getVal()
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution was (*it)->getVal()